# simple html/jquery issue with <div> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I am trying to use a solution that was provided here (thank you stackoverflow :-)), but I cannot get it to work on my site.
The goal is to have radio buttons that, when clicked will open a div with more text and a checkbox.
For this I included the jquery library :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and the script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("[name=toggler]").click(function(){
                $('.toHide').hide();
                $("#blk-"+$(this).val()).show('slow');
        });
     });
</script>
```

in my header.

### here is the code :

```
<div style='padding-left:20px;'>
    <h2>Please select one of the following options: A, B or C</h2>
    <br>
    <br>
    <form name='wtfpol'>
        <label>
            <input type='radio' name='toggler' value='1' id='1' />OPTION A:</label>
        <br />
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type='radio' name='toggler' value='2' id='2' />OPTION B: >
        </label>
        <br />
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type='radio' name='toggler' value='3' id='3' />OPTION C: I</label>
        <br />
        <br>
</div>
<div id='blk-1' class='toHide' style='display:none; padding-left:20px;'>
    blah blah blah
</div>

<div id='blk-2' class='toHide' style='display:none; padding-left:20px;'>
    blah blah blah 2
</div>
<div id='blk-3' class='toHide' style='display:none; padding-left:20px;'>
    blah blah blah 2
</div>
```

---

What am I missing ?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: can you demonstrate it on this fiddle? what is not working? https://jsfiddle.net/buj04d5w/

Comment: is jQuery included in your site?

Comment: Add jQuery library above you custom script.

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually works, you just aren't including thejQuery library!

https://jsfiddle.net/zhpwLoj5/

Add jQuery in the head of your HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: actually I am including this :
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: If you look at the jsfiddle I created - using your code - it is working.

Comment: I did ! (thank you) and I even included my own code (with all texts and stuff and it is also working...) I  have some content below the texts, could that be an issue ?

Comment: If your code isn't working locally then it is highly likely that you have some kind of conflict, or other error yes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include a higher version of Jquery I guess, this will work..

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("[name=toggler]").click(function(){
                $('.toHide').hide();
                $("#blk-"+$(this).val()).show('slow');
        });
     });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style='padding-left:20px;'>
<h2>Please select one of the following options: A, B or C</h2><br><br>
<form name='wtfpol'>
<label> <input type='radio' name='toggler' value='1' id='1' />OPTION A:</label><br /><br>
<label> <input type='radio' name='toggler' value='2' id='2' />OPTION B: 
</label><br /><br>
<label> <input type='radio' name='toggler' value='3' id='3' />OPTION C: I</label><br /><br>
</div>
<div id='blk-1' class='toHide' style='display:none; padding-left:20px;'>
blah blah blah
</div>

<div id='blk-2' class='toHide' style='display:none; padding-left:20px;'>
blah blah blah 2
</div>
<div id='blk-3' class='toHide' style='display:none; padding-left:20px;'>
blah blah blah 2
</div>
</body>
</html>
```